# bind JSON file to Echarts (JQuery get)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, echarts

I want to import my JSON file to Echarts to make a line chart but failed, the result page is totally blank. I search it in google but couldn't find a proper answer.

This is the JSON:

```
[
  { "category": "A", "value": 1 },
  { "category": "B", "value": 2 },
  { "category": "C", "value": 3 },
  { "category": "D", "value": 7 }
]
```

```js
var dataArr = [];
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('demo'));

$.get('data.json', {}, function(response) {
  dataArr = JSON.parse(response);
  initEchart();
});

function initEchart() {
  // specify chart configuration item and data
  var option = {
    title: {
      text: 'entry example'
    },
    tooltip: {},
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: dataArr.category
    },
    yAxis: {},
    series: [{
      type: 'line',
      data: dataArr.value
    }]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.7.0/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha256-eKrx6Ly6b0Rscx/PSm52rJsvK76RJyv18Toswq+OLSs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="demo" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Thank you for helping me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your version. You tried to pass to the chart empty data because key `dataArr.category` does not exist. You received array so need collect data with loop: `dataArr.map(row => row['category'])` and will be ok.

```js
var dataArr = [];
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('demo'));

$.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/creadone/d15105b0c7e33848ef9559c28a9912c2/raw/64a17c5ac38b375cd6ab858d51a66836d9259ed0/data.json', {}, function(response) {
  dataArr = JSON.parse(response);
 console.log(dataArr);
  initEchart();
});

function initEchart() {
  // specify chart configuration item and data
  var option = {
    title: {
      text: 'entry example'
    },
    tooltip: {},
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: dataArr.map(row => row['category'])
    },
    yAxis: {},
    series: [{
      type: 'line',
      data: dataArr.map(row => row['value'])
    }]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.7.0/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha256-eKrx6Ly6b0Rscx/PSm52rJsvK76RJyv18Toswq+OLSs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="demo" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I use your code and it works well. But if I use $.gets ('data.json') instead of your url, it'll fail(the content is exactly the same). Does it mean that I can't use local files but a url?

Comment: What you see in Chrome developer console? Probaby it's Chrome [CORS policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/190266/why-chrome-blocks-ajax-locally). You can run HTML with any server locally (I prefer https://www.browsersync.io as plugin to https://gulpjs.com/) or run Chrome with allow flags `--allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access` but this is unsafe.